# Screen scrolling in Google Chrome (overflow not working)

Tags: css, wordpress, overflow

I am trying to stop the horizontal scroll here : http://imaginationmuzic.com/

but to no avail, if you check the css overflow-x: hidden is there attached to the html and body in the CSS.  It doesn't work in Chrome or Safari.

Comment: I don't see any horizontal scrolling when I look at it. It is cut off though which is what overflow hidden should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "position: relative" to your css for the #wrapper element like so:

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1200px;
    text-align: left;
    background: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```